# Empty Layout with using include

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer

I'm using navigation drawer. But my layout keep looking empty. Any idea to solution? Why does it look like empty? Here is my code. I dont share my Java code, because I dont think the problem is in there.

**app_bar_ipuclari.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.yunus.ototakip.IpuclariSayfasi">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/beyaz"
    app:subtitleTextColor="@color/beyaz">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/tarihView"
    android:layout_height="35dp">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bugün -"
        android:textColor="@color/beyaz"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingLeft="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/tarihText">


    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
app:itemIconTint="@color/beyaz"
app:itemTextColor="@color/beyaz"
app:menu="@menu/bottombar_menu" />

<include layout="@layout/content_ipuclari_sayfasi"/> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_ipuclari_sayfasi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_ipuclari_sayfasi"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.yunus.ototakip.IpuclariSayfasi"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_ipuclari">


<CheckBox
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="257dp"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox" /></RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_ipuclari_sayfasi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `app_bar_ipuclari.xml` file you didn't close the tag

```
<include layout="@layout/content_ipuclari_sayfasi"/
```

add this `>` in the end.

Also try to move **Toolbar** into **AppBarLayout**

Comment: Then try to move Toolbar

Comment: still empty my friend

Comment: @YunusHaznedar, Hmm, try to move **RelativeLayout** and **BottomNavigationView** to `content.xml`